# How to make X axis timescale with equal interval between elements on chart independent of time range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I need to display elements on my chart with equal interval between elements with dates ticks on X axis. Elements have different interval because they have scaled by date range. Is it possible to display some elements on chart with equal interval between them regardless of dates on X axis?

I have tried to use different scales like bandscale and linearscale. But they works incorrect when i am trying to pass my min and max dates to domain function.

For example this chart:
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/Overview/jQuery/Light/

I need the same equal distance between dots but have dates on my X axis instead of names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is more important to have the bars equally spaced than to have them spaced according to their time value, use `d3.scaleBand()` and pass to the domain the full array of dates that are represented in the dataset, e.g., `.domain(data.map(d => d.date))`.